# drawing multiple objects in OpenGL

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I started learning OpenGL. I can load a .obj model and draw it with an elementBuffer. But I'm stuck at trying to two different models at a time. The model I want to draw is in an Entity class.
Most tutorials I can find about this only shows how to load and draw a sinlge model. None explains (In a way I can find/understand at least) how to handle multiple models.

Here is all my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws LWJGLException, IOException
{
    PixelFormat pixelFormat = new PixelFormat();
    ContextAttribs contextAtrributes = new ContextAttribs(3, 2);
    contextAtrributes.withForwardCompatible(true);
    contextAtrributes.withProfileCore(true);

    Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
    Display.setTitle("Textured quad!");
    Display.create(pixelFormat, contextAtrributes);

    Mouse.create();
    Mouse.setGrabbed(true);
    Keyboard.create();

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

    entity = new Entity("planeTex.obj");
    entity2 = new Entity("modelTex2.obj");

    Shaders.load();
    Textures.load();
    Camera.create(new Vector3f(0, 1, -0.75f), new Vector3f(-50, 0, 20), HEIGHT, WIDTH);

    while (!Display.isCloseRequested())
    {

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        entity.draw();
        entity2.draw();

        Display.update();
        Display.sync(60);
    }

}

public class Entity
{
    private int vao, vbo, ebo;
    private int elementSize;

    public Entity(String name)
    {
        vao = glGenVertexArrays();
        glBindVertexArray(vao);
        vbo = glGenBuffers();
        *Load vertex data into buffer*
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        ebo = glGenBuffers();
        *load data into elementBuffer*
        *Set elementSize to the element count*
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo);
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, elementBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    }

    public void draw()
    {
        glBindVertexArray(vao);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo);

        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, elementSize, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    }
}

public class Shaders
{

public static int vertexShader, fragmentShader;
public static int shaderProgram;
public static int uniTrans;

    public static void load()
    {
        vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(vertexShader, loadFile("vertex.shader"));
        glCompileShader(vertexShader);

        fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(fragmentShader, loadFile("fragment.shader"));
        glCompileShader(fragmentShader);


        shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
        glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
        glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
        glBindFragDataLocation(shaderProgram, 0, "outColor");
        glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
        glUseProgram(shaderProgram);


        // Specify the layout of the vertex data
        int posAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "position");
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(posAttrib);
        glVertexAttribPointer(posAttrib, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, (Float.SIZE / 8) * 8, 0);

        int colAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "color");
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(colAttrib);
        glVertexAttribPointer(colAttrib, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, (Float.SIZE / 8) * 8, (Float.SIZE / 8) * 3);

        int texAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "texcoord");
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(texAttrib);
        glVertexAttribPointer(texAttrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, (Float.SIZE / 8) * 8, (Float.SIZE / 8) * 6);

        uniTrans = glGetUniformLocation(Shaders.shaderProgram, "model");
    }
}
```

The result is that only the Entity object created last will be drawn. No matter the draw order.

Comment: "vao, vbo and ebo are all global integers" - you mean `static` variables? Then this is the problem.

Comment: @kerim, They are not static. I updated the question to show exactly how the class looks.

Comment: Another note - you don't need to call `glBindBuffer` after `glBindVertexArray` in `draw`. You already associated those buffers with the VAO in constructor.

Comment: Actually I could be wrong, as I'm sure about this only when you use `glVertexAttribPointer`. I don't know how VAO works without vertex attrib stuff...

Comment: Where's the rest of the code? The part that calls some function of the form `gl*Pointer` and `glEnableClientState` or `glEnableVertexAttribArray`? And what about your shaders?

Comment: @NicolBolas I added the rest of the code I use. The Textures class and the shaders itself aren't posted though, as drawing a single model is all good, so I doubt that's why? I hope what I've posted is good enough to go on.

Comment: @RenéJensen: "*Specify the layout of the vertex data*" No; that's not how it works. I would provide a detailed answer, but I already have [a good OpenGL Wiki article](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification) that explains it all in meticulous detail. In brief, all of that stuff goes into the VAO setup in your entity; it's not part of the shader object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I fixed it by placing this chunk
        // Specify the layout of the vertex data
        int posAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(Shaders.shaderProgram, "position");
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(posAttrib);
        glVertexAttribPointer(posAttrib, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, (Float.SIZE / 8) * 8, 0);

```
    int colAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(Shaders.shaderProgram, "color");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(colAttrib);
    glVertexAttribPointer(colAttrib, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, (Float.SIZE / 8) * 8, (Float.SIZE / 8) * 3);

    int texAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(Shaders.shaderProgram, "texcoord");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(texAttrib);
    glVertexAttribPointer(texAttrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, (Float.SIZE / 8) * 8, (Float.SIZE / 8) * 6);
```

In the entity class draw loop just before the glDrawElements method. Placing the chunk anywhere else would result in a crashed program:

> "Cannot use offsets when Array Buffer Object is disabled"

Otherwise it would simply draw nothing at all. I got the feeling from NicolBolas that I should put it in the Entity constructor, but as I said, it didn't work anywhere.